# Android SafeArgs destination value is always default

Tags: java, android, kotlin

So I have an android app with mixed kotlin and java classes due to it being an update on an older app. Long story short, we're using Navigation component and SafeArgs, I'm able to set the values on the argument properly (Kotlin class) but when I try to access the args in the destination (Android class) I always end up getting the default value set in the navigation.xml

Here are my codes:

Source (KOTLIN) :

```
//val actionDetail = FirstFragmentDirections.actionFirstToSecond("I am the source")
val actionDetail = FirstFragmentDirections.actionFirstToSecond()
actionDetail.chatSource = "I am the source"
navController.navigate(actionDetail)
```

and then my navigation.xml looks like:

```
<fragment
        android:id="@+id/nave_chat"
        android:name="ChatFragment"
        android:label=""
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_chat" >
        <argument
            android:name="chatSource"
            app:argType="string"
            app:nullable="true"
            android:defaultValue="firstboot" />
    </fragment>
```

lastly ChatFragment (JAVA) looks like:

```
String chatSource = requireArguments().getString("chatSource");
Log.d("MIKE LOG","CHAT SOURCE IS: " + chatSource);
String chatSource2 = getArguments().getString("chatSource");
Log.d("MIKE LOG","CHAT SOURCE 2 IS: " + chatSource2);
String vals = ChatFragmentArgs.fromBundle(getArguments()).getChatSource();
Log.d("MIKE LOG","CHAT SOURCE 3 IS: " + vals);
```

all values here are coming as "firstboot" instead of the expected "I am the source".

Any help would be very much welcome, been dealing with this the whole day. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try removing `app:defaultValue` in the argument

Comment: i have checked my SafeArgs app, it seems android:name in fragment tag is not linked to which fragment you are accessing. It should look something like android:name="com.myapp.folders.yourfragmentname"

Comment: Hi, yes the android:name in the xml is actually like that, I just simplified it for this post as the actual one was quite a lengthy one. Thank you. still dumbfounded why I can't get the proper values here. Could it be that the value is set on Kotlin and then being read using Java?

Comment: not sure why it didn't work for you, you could try adding .text or .toString().